# How to generate selection box and text field dynamically in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the following code, I am trying to generate a selection box and text field every time a user presses Add button. The problem that I am facing is that how I can generate a new text field with different name. As you can see in the code, the name of the text box is `text1`. How can I generate a new text box with a name `text2`, for example.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><center>Querying Social Media</center></h1>
    <form>
        <center>
            <select>
                <option value="Author">Author</option>
                <option value="Mention">Mention</option>
                <option value="Tag">Tag</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" name="text1">
            <select>
                <option value="And">And</option>
                <option value="Or">Or</option>  
            </select>
            <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add(document.forms[0].element.value)"/>
            <script language="javascript">
                function add(type) {
                    //Create an input type dynamically.
                    var element = document.createElement("input");

                    //Assign different attributes to the element.
                    element.setAttribute("type", type);
                    element.setAttribute("value", type);
                    element.setAttribute("name", type);

                    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

                    //Append the element in page (in span).
                    foo.appendChild(element);
                }
            </SCRIPT>
        </center>
    </form>
    <span id="fooBar">&nbsp;</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you need only one text input i.e., text2 or multiple like text3, text4, text 5 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

you can make three global variables for all three type and every time add function called you make increment on global viable depending on type and then set the name of textbox like (textbox_1,textbox_2, ...) . 
what you think>

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this:

```js
function add(type, value, name) {

  //Create an input type dynamically.
  var element = document.createElement("input");

  //Assign different attributes to the element.
  element.setAttribute("type", type);
  element.setAttribute("value", value);
  element.setAttribute("name", name);

  var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

  //Append the element in page (in span).
  foo.appendChild(element);
}

add("input","someValue", "text2");
```

```html
<span id="fooBar"></span>
```